# Foreach in CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am calculating the **total_brb_time** but not being able to calculate it for every employee. Actually i want to add **total_brb_time** to the **atendance** array and want to pass it to a view called **'attendance-sheet'**.

[image: Screenshot]

This is my controller:

```
public function generate_report()
{
    if ($_GET) 
    {
        $fromDate   = $this->input->get('fromDate',TRUE);
        $toDate     = $this->input->get('toDate',TRUE);
        $employeeId = $this->input->get('employeeId',TRUE);

        if ($employeeId == 'none') 
        {
            $data['attendance'] = $this->Attendance_Model->filter_attendance_for_report($fromDate, $toDate);
        }
        else
        {
            $data['attendance'] = $this->Attendance_Model->filter_user_attendance_for_report($fromDate, $toDate, $employeeId);
        }

        foreach ($data as $att) 
        {

            $attDate    = $att[0]->date;
            $attUserId  = $att[0]->user_id;

            $brb        = $this->Brb_Model->filter_brb_for_report($attDate, $attUserId);

            foreach ($brb as $b) 
            {
                $brbTime    = $b->brb_time;
                $backTime   = $b->back_time;
                $brbDate    = $b->date;

                $start_time = new DateTime($brbDate.$brbTime);
                $end_time   = new DateTime($brbDate.$backTime);

                $dateDiff       = $start_time->diff($end_time);
                $brb_time[]     = $dateDiff->format("%H:%I:%S");
            }

            $sum  = strtotime('00:00:00');
            $sum2 = 0;

            foreach ($brb_time as $v)
            {
                $sum1 = strtotime($v) - $sum;
                $sum2 = $sum2 + $sum1;
            }

            $sum3 = $sum + $sum2;

            $total_brb_time  = date("H:i:s", $sum3);
            $data['brbtime'] = $total_brb_time;
        }

        $data['employees'] = $this->User_Model->get_users();
        $this->load->view('attendance-sheet', $data);
    }
}
```

This is my `Attendance_Model` function:

```
public function filter_attendance_results($query)
{
    $sql = 'select attendance_id, date, time_in, time_out, notes, working_hours, a.user_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.team, a.designation from users AS a
            LEFT JOIN attendance on a.user_id= attendance.user_id ';
    $sql .= 'where 1=1 '.$query ;

    $query = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
    return $query;
}



public function filter_attendance_for_report($date1, $date2)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('attendance')
    ->join('users', 'attendance.user_id = users.user_id')
    ->where('date >=', $date1)
    ->where('date <=', $date2)
    ->order_by("date", "asc")
    ->get();

    return $query->result();
}



public function filter_user_attendance_for_report($date1, $date2, $user_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('attendance')
    ->join('users', 'attendance.user_id = users.user_id')
    ->where('date >=', $date1)
    ->where('date <=', $date2)
    ->where('attendance.user_id =', $user_id)
    ->order_by("date", "asc")
    ->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

I want to show the total brb of every employee in table row. But it is showing only the first calculated brb at every row. And this is view:

```
                             <div class="x_content">
                              <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>Working Hours</th>
                                    <th>Total BRB Time</th>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead>


                                <tbody>
                                  <?php
                                  $i = 1;
                                   foreach ($attendance as $att): 
                                    ?>
                                  <tr>
                                      <th scope="row"><?= $i++ ?></th>
                                      <td><?= $att->first_name .'&nbsp;'. $att->last_name ?></td>
                                      <td><?= $att->date ?></td>
                                      <td><?= $att->working_hours ?></td>
                                      <td><?= $brbtime ?></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Did you check `$attendance` value?

Comment: Yeah. i checked it. Attendance array is working fine. Just want to calculate the value of total_brb_time for each employee is failed.

Comment: Do you help to specify a solution. I have added the screen shot also.

Comment: `$data['brbtime'] = $total_brb_time;` is overwritten in each loop. Add it as field to your `$attendance` array

Answer (score 0):

in line `$data['brbtime'] = $total_brb_time;` you adding key `brbtime` to all array `$data`. If you want to add `brbtime` to each element of array `$data` do next:

instead `foreach ($data as $att)` change to `foreach ($data as $key=>$att)`

instead `$data['brbtime'] = $total_brb_time;` change to `$data[$key]['brbtime'] = $total_brb_time;`

Comment: and how to catch its value in view?

Comment: use `$att->brbtime;` @MuahmmadUmarBilal

Comment: Can you add `var_dump($attendance);` before `foreach` in view ?

Comment: i do it. it is showing just first time calculated brbtime at the end of the whole array

Comment: You can check the screen shot i have attached in starting of my post. So that you can better understand the issue and can solve it according to your style.

Comment: It becouse you did not apply changes as in my answer

Comment: Change `foreach ($data as $key=>$att)`  to `foreach ($data['attendance'] as $key=>$att)` and `$data[$key]['brbtime'] = $total_brb_time;` to `$data['attendance'][$key]['brbtime'] = $total_brb_time;`

Comment: Error : Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: $data['attendance'][$key]['brbtime'] = $total_brb_time;

Comment: try `$data['attendance']->$key['brbtime']`

Comment: Attempt to modify property of non-object... on same line